# Execute a widget function in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to execute a function in an iframe from the parent page of that frame. Both are on the same domain.
The function is part of a widget on the child page, and this is activated on page load.

```
function(){apex.jQuery(document).apex_save_before_exit({...});};;
```

A piece of the widget code:

```
(function($){
$.widget('ui.apex_save_before_exit', {
   options: {
      saveMessage: null,
      noWarningSelector: null,
      disableTime: null,
      ignoreChangeSelector: null
   },
   values: {
      itemChanged: false,
      promptUser: true,
      forcePrompt: false,
      debug: $('#pdebug').length !== 0
   },
   _create: function() {      
   ...
   },
   ...,
   changeDetected: function() {
      var uiw = this;
      var somethingChanged;
   ...
```

I know the widget works because when i try it in the iframe (and when not in the iframe), it works as i'd expect.

But i'd like to call the `changeDetected` function from the parent page.
Note: i'm running these from the firebug console!

```
window.frames['cbox1346667865025'].document.apex_save_before_exit('changeDetected')
```

Yields

```
TypeError: window.frames.cbox1346667865025.document.apex_save_before_exit is not a function
```

Same when using

```
$('iframe.cboxIframe')[0].contentWindow.document 
or
$('iframe.cboxIframe').contents()
```

Yields

```
TypeError: $("iframe.cboxIframe").contents().apex_save_before_exit is not a function
```

What am i doing wrong? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of an iframe are on a different domain to the one outside the iframe, then you can't do this.

Also you probably want the actual element instead of a jquery object, so instead do:

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').document.someFunction(arg1, arg2,...);
```

Comment: Both pages are on the same domain (this is my 2nd sentence in the op ;) ). I tried with both jquery object as html dom object: `windows.frames` is pure javascript, and the jquery `[0]` returns a html dom element. Those don't work, and `.contents()` just as less. I see no reason why `getElementById` would work different than all the others, and even then the iframe has no `id` attribute.

Comment: Then try giving the iframe an id and getting it that way?

Comment: I did, but results are the same. I have to use `.contentWindow` though, `.document` is `undefined` -> `document.getElementById('cbiframe').document`